Laravel first-party vs third-party tokens
I am working on a laravel project where API is authenticated via OAuth. Tokens are issued to first-party and third-party clients to interact with the API. However, we want to block specific actions (e.g., account management, cancellation, etc) by the third-party tokens.
Scopes seem like the right approach to this—issue the scopes to the first party, not the third party. However, our application has not yet been designed to handle scopes. It will be a bigger refactor. Is there something we can check in the middleware and then deny the request?
Something like
request()->bearerToken()->firstParty() 

Or any other approaches? FWIW our firstParty tokens have * as the scope.
